# Selecting unique observations in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` data frame with a column `uniqueid`. I would like to remove all duplicates from the data frame based on this column, such that all remaining observations are unique.

Comment: supposing that there are two rows with same value in column uniqueid.  Does it matter which row you remove?

Comment: No, it does not matter in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is also the `drop_duplicates()` method for any data frame ([docs here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicates#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates)).  You can pass specific columns to drop from as an argument.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='uniqueid', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect way to go

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`duplicated` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas.Series.duplicated)

Since we only care if `uniqueid` (`A` in my example) is duplicated, select that and call `duplicated` on that series. Then use the `~` to flip the bools.

```
In [90]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

In [91]: df
Out[91]: 
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  b  3
3  c  4

In [92]: df['A'].duplicated()
Out[92]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [93]: df.loc[~df['A'].duplicated()]
Out[93]: 
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
3  c  4
```