# Delete the entire row if the a value in value is equal to previous row in Python

Tags: python, duplicates, duplication

I am new to python programming and I need a help to delete the entire row based on the value of a single column in a dataframe. I want to delete the row, if a value in a single column is equal to the previous row value.

The following is my data,

```
  x.id x.timestamp x.count
71    1  1435114605      61
72    1  1435114606      61
73    1  1435114659      61
74    1  1435114719      62
75    1  1435114726      62
76    1  1435114780      62
77    1  1435155998      62
78    1  1435156059      62
79    1  1435156076      62
80    1  1435156119      62
```

Here I want to delete the rows based on the x.x.count value.

My Output should be,

```
  x.id x.timestamp x.count
71    1  1435114605      61
74    1  1435114719      62
```

I can't use drop_duplicates function because the values would be reoccuring later in the column. I want to check the previous value and delete it.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to delete rows only if they match the previous row on any column, not if they match _any_ row on a given value?

Comment: @CodyBraun only on a particular column, here based on the x.count column

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718531/selecting-unique-observations-in-a-pandas-data-frame duplicated is what you're looking for. I'm sure another gent on here will have your answer spun up here shortly

Comment: @FirebladeDan We can use drop_duplicates here, But I dont want to use that here, because my column have counter values which reoccur later. So I want to do it based on the previous value only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to just drop dupes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.groupby((df["x.count"] != df["x.count"].shift()).cumsum().values).first()
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df["x.count"].shift() != df["x.count"]]
```